# Seeking Javascript API for weather data?

Tags: javascript, data, software-recommendations, weather

I'm looking for a good javascript api which gives access to a weather data-base.
I want to extract information like average number of rain days, amount of sunshine and average temperature.

Is there an api or an openly available database with information like that available?

Answer (score 1):

OpenWeatherMap is a good JavaScript API.
http://openweathermap.org/API

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jquery.simpleWeather](http://simpleweatherjs.com/), a simple jQuery plugin to display the weather information for any location. The data is pulled from the public Yahoo! Weather feed via the YQL API.

Don't miss the demo, to see a real world example of how to display and style the weather.